# Solve integral equation for upper bound

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations

I need to find the upper bound of an integral knowing the value of the lower bound and the result of the integral.

Here is my function:

```
f[t_] = Sqrt[1 + E^(-2 t)]
```

I need to integrate it between 0 and t, and the result of the integral should be 10. Also t > 0.

Hope that makes sense. I'd be really tankful if someone could show me how to do that.

Comment: Start with this `Plot[NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + E^(-2 t)], {t, 0, x}], {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Ok and then I went with this:
Clear[x]

    x = x /. FindRoot[
    NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + E^(-2 t)], {t, 0, x}] == 10, {x, 10}] // Quiet

Comment: It gives me an answer: 9.77401 Is that my upper bound for the initial integral?

Comment: Right! Well done. `k = FindRoot[
   NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + E^(-2 t)], {t, 0, x}] == 10, {x, 10}] //   Quiet; NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + E^(-2 t)], {t, 0, x /. k}]`

Comment: OK nice! I guess I could just integrate the original function between 0 and 9.77401 and that would give me 10 (as a proof). Thanks for the help

Comment: That's what I did right above :D